# Java Program That Checks If Numbers Between Given Ranges Are Palindromes

Tags: java, loops, range, palindrome

so I'm trying to write this java program that will check and display all palindrome numbers between 0 and 10000. The method isPalindrome has to take an int 
number and return a boolean true if number is palindrome and false if its not a palindrome.

Here's my code so far but when I run it, it only prints a line of 1's 
The print I added at the end is to debug and check if the method works but it this case it doesn't. I also initialized the numCount to 1 because I couldn't figure out how to make the method work when num has to be bigger than 0. Initializing numCount to 0 would make the program skip the whole num > 0 part.

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;

public class PalindromeCheck 
{

    public static void main(String [] args)
    { 
        //variables 
        int numCount = 1;
        final int END = 10000;
        boolean palindrome; 

        //methods
        palindrome = isPalindrome(numCount, END);

    }//end main 
    public static boolean isPalindrome(int numCount, int END)
    { 

        //local variables 
        int num, num2 = numCount, remainder, reverseNum;
        boolean palindrome;
        palindrome = false;


        while (numCount <= END)
        {

            num = numCount;
            remainder = 0;
            reverseNum = 0;

                while (num > 0)
                {


                    remainder = num % 10;
                    num = num / 10;
                    reverseNum = (reverseNum * 10) + remainder;

                    if (reverseNum == num2)
                    {   
                        palindrome = true;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        palindrome = false;
                    }

                        if(palindrome == true)
                        {
                            System.out.print("  " + reverseNum);
                        }



                 }//end Minor Loop

            numCount++;

        }//end of Major Loop

        return palindrome;
    }//end of method isPalindrome

}//end of class
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider working with strings to represent the palindrome.

Comment: but i want to check numbers not strings

Comment: The `StringBuilder` class has a method for reversing strings.  It is very easy to use.

Comment: You see I'm a first year computer science student and I am not yet familiar with that class

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to find **Palindromes** without using `StringBuilder`

```
 public boolean isPalindrome(int number){ 
   //number=12321
   int num = number;
   //reversing number
   int reverse=0,rmd; 
   while(number > 0) 
   { 
     rmd = number % 10; 
     reverse = reverse * 10 + rmd; 
     number = number / 10; 
   } 
   if(reverse == num) 
     //true
   else
     //false
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number to a StringBuilder object then use the reverse method in the StringBuilder class to create a new StringBuilder object, then compare the contents of the two StringBuilder objects.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using classes because i have not yet learned that

Comment: Everything in Java is in classes.

Comment: But till now i only know of the Math class so i dont know how to use this StringBuilder class ur talking about

Comment: i need to write this program using a numDigit method that takes an int and returns the number of digits of that int and the isPalindrome method that takes an int and returns a boolean true if the number is a palindrome and false if its not

Answer (score 0):

Your num2 does not increase as your numCount.  While your numCount is incremented at the end of the loop, num2 is always 1 as num2 is not set to equal to numCount every time when the loop starts.

```
if (reverseNum == num2)
```

So the above is true only if reverseNum == 1
Add a line in your code and it should work

```
while (numCount <= END)
    {
        if (numCount == 0)  // special case for 0
        {
            System.out.print("0");
            numCount++;
            continue;
        }

        num = numCount;
        num2 = numCount;   // <- add this line

        // your original code here

    }//end of Major Loop
```

Comment: thank you could you explain more in specific why my code wasnt working?

Comment: how can I make it so the program can start at 0 instead of 1? because num has to be bigger than 0 so the program enters the loop

Comment: I would just add a "if" line for 0, as it is a special case under your code.